# Browser commenting out the code inserted using JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to insert php echo statement into a div tag , using JS , 
But the browser is commenting out the code.

```
   <!--?php echo $desci[1]?-->
```

Here is my code, I am new to JS , Please help

```
   $('.wrapinner').click(function(e) {
         $('.wrapinner').css("margin-top","0");
         $('.wrapinner').css("opacity","0.4");
         $(this).css("margin-top","25px");
         $(this).css("opacity","1");
         var id = this.id;
         var str = "<";
         str+= "?php echo $desci[";
         str+= id;
         str+= "]?>";
         document.getElementById("con").innerHTML=str;

    });
```

Comment: Importantly, why are you trying to add PHP statements into your HTML code?

Comment: I think you need to google the difference between client side code and server side code.

Comment: I ma just trying to add it as a string. into the html .

Comment: I don't see why this is being down-voted tbh. They had a problem and came here for help. Its just a mistake they have made and I don't think its necessary to down-vote something like this.

Comment: @CleanX What do you mean? If you want to output it as text thats possible. If you want to try run the code then no. Its a server side language. JS is client-side.

Comment: thanks ruddy , but is my question not valid? I just have a JS using which am changing a block of text which I have retrieved from db, when user clicks on a selection , It should replace the desc by the desc of the selected item.

Comment: @CleanX PHP must run serverside. When the page is loaded the code is ran on the server. If you insert PHP after that then it will do nothing as its not being read by the server, it is now being read by the client. This is why your JQuery works dynamically and you can view its code via the browser. Hope this helps.

Comment: `insert php` ... `into a div` ... `using JS` .... say what?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , Am sorry if my question offended you , I am newbie.

Comment: @CleanX no offence at all, I was suggesting how you can discover the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     var str = "<";
     str+= "?php echo $desci[";
     str+= id;
     str+= "]?>";
     document.getElementById("con").innerHTML=str;
```

When you assign something to `innerHTML`, it is *parsed* as HTML.

`<?php echo $desci[1]?>` is no valid HTML code however. In XML, it *might* be considered as a processing instruction (those start with `<?`) – but not one that your browser will understand.

If you just want to display this as *text* – then either *assign* it as text:

```
document.getElementById("con").textContent=str;
```

or make your string content not be interpretable as HTML in the first place, by escaping `<` and `>` the proper way, as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.